# Extend Optional and Non-Optional Type

Tags: swift

I am interacting with a C API. For memory safety I chose to not keep the C types internally and just produce them when another C api needs them, so I can work with plain Swift structs instead. In this example I just use the `Foo` type as a stand-in, this is obviously not the real type.

Now when I need to call a C API, I have those 2 methods on the type, to produce a C pointer I can work with:

```swift
struct Foo {
    let bar: Int
}

extension Optional where Wrapped == Foo {

    func withUnsafePointer<T>(_ block: (Foo?) throws -> T) rethrows -> T {
        guard let self = self else {
            return try block(nil)
        }
        return try block(self)
    }
}

extension Foo {

    func withUnsafePointer<T>(_ block: (Foo) throws -> T) rethrows -> T {
        return try block(self)
    }
}
```

As you can see I need to extend the optional as well to facilitate this. Otherwise a call to `foo?.withUnsafePointer(...)` would just not be executed.

I don't find this pattern particularly pretty. Is there a better option instead of implementing the method twice?

The whole point of this is, that the C object should only have a limited lifetime (here inside the block).

Comment: Not related to your question but there is no need to contrain your extension generic type to Foo unless you want to restrict the usage to a single type `extension Optional {` `func withUnsafePointer<T>(_ block: (Wrapped?) throws -> T) rethrows -> T {`

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid duplicating the `withUnsafePointer` method by declaring a protocol, making both `Foo` and `Foo?` conform to it, and then extending the protocol. This isn't necessarily as pretty as something like `extension Foo, Optional<Foo>` would be, but AFAIK there's not currently a way to do that in Swift as of the time of this writing.

```
struct Foo {
    let myCPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: 1)
}

protocol HasMyCPointer {
    associatedtype MyCPointerType
    var myCPointer: MyCPointerType { get }
}

extension Foo: HasMyCPointer {}

extension Optional: HasMyCPointer where Wrapped == Foo {
    var myCPointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>? { self?.myCPointer }
}

extension HasMyCPointer {
    func withUnsafePointer<T>(_ block: (Self.MyCPointerType) throws -> T) rethrows -> T {
        return try block(self.myCPointer)
    }
}

let foo = Foo()
let bar: Foo? = nil
let baz: Foo? = Foo()

foo.withUnsafePointer {
    print("Foo: \($0)")
}

bar.withUnsafePointer {
    print("Bar: \($0 as Any)")
}

baz.withUnsafePointer {
    print("Baz: \($0 as Any)")
}
```

prints:

```
Foo: 0x00007fade3c05750
Bar: nil
Baz: Optional(0x00007fade3c00220)
```

Comment: I'm afraid thats even more complicated as the original approach. Also this specific implementation wouldn't work in my case because the pointer needs to be destroyed after `block` was called, so there couldn't be a `var myCPointer`.

Comment: Yeah, I hear that. Unfortunately I don't think Swift currently has the mechanism to do precisely what you want. The trouble is that you need the block signatures to be different—one with an optional pointer and one without, which makes this tough.

With that said, this implementation can be modified to do what you want without too much trouble; just replace `var myCPointer` with two functions in the protocol: `func makeMyCPointer` and `func destroyMyCPointer` (obviously give them better names).